# get the image size with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

i am using js for dynamic content

now i want to get the size (width and height) of an image

until now i used `img.clientWidth` and `img.clientHeight` but when i have set `img.style.width` and `img.style.height` the `img.clientWidth` and `img.clientHeight` changed as well.
i need a variable which does not change during the webpage changes, since the src does not change as well.
if there is any way, i would prefer no jquery

Comment: What do you mean by “the size”? The natural, intrinsic size, or what?

Comment: the given question is _not_ a duplicate because it doesn't address this OP's issue that the `height` (and `.style.height`) properties are affected by CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the *original* (intrinsic) size of the image file, use the `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` properties of the element, if available.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the value.

```
var imgH = img.clientHeight;
```

Then even if it changes, imgH will have the height from when you defined it.